# Validating a choice field against an array Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, validation

I am building a form class in Symfony2. In my class, I have a choice field. I built a function to return my choice array:

```
public function getCardTypes()  {
    return array('visa' => 'Visa', 'mc' => 'MasterCard', 'amex' => 'American Express');
}
```

Later, I add a choice field to my form with this array:

```
$builder->add('PaymentCCType', 'choice', array('choices' => $this->getCardTypes()));
```

And then in getDefaultOptions function I have a choice constraint for this field:

```
'PaymentCCType' => new Choice(array('choices' => $this->getCardTypes())),
```

I seem to be having a problem with this validator. When I submit this form, I get the following error underneath my select box: "The value you selected is not a valid choice". Of course, I am using one of the choices in my array.

What am I doing wrong?

/* edit */

I have noticed that of the 4 fields I have like this, I only get the error on 3 of them. the one where the choice is month (simple 1-12), validation works.

/* edit 2 */

the issue appears to occur when the array key does not match the value. i switched my array to `array('Visa' => 'Visa', 'MasterCard' => 'MasterCard', 'American Express' => 'American Express')` and now it works.
Is there any way around this? I feel like I can't be the only one with this issue. it occurs even when you have a regular (non-associative) array like `array('Visa', 'MasterCard', 'American Express')`

Comment: I don't think you have to add this in the getDefaultOptions method. Try your form with just the `$builder->add(...)` code.

Comment: @AdrienBrault I'm following this guide here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#adding-validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*edit*
In response to my issue, the Symfony team pointed out the choice validator accepts an array of possible values (not possible choices like the choice field). the easiest way to do this is to use the array_keys function:

`'PaymentCCType' => new Choice(array('choices' => array_keys($this->getCardTypes()))),`

Answer (score 3):

IMHO you should do it in different way, create class with ChoiceListInterface with methods:

```
public function getChoices() 
{   
    return self::$choices;  
}

public static function getTypeChoicesKeys() 
{
    return array_keys(self::$choices);
}
```

in form class:

```
$builder->add('type', 'choice', 
        array(
            'expanded' => true, 
            'multiple' => false,
            'choice_list' => new TypeChoices(),
            'required' => true,
        )
      )
```

in validation.yml

```
    type:
        - NotNull: ~
        - Choice: { callback: [TypeChoices, getTypeChoicesKeys] }
```

Comment: I feel like this is a bit ridiculous. I have to create a separate class file, in a new folder, to create/validate an select with 3 options?

Comment: I feel the same way first time. Now I don't care.

Comment: It makes sense for some things (particularly large choice sets like country), but here I am really trying to keep the form all in one place.

Comment: If you are going to localize etc. application using separate class makes sense